# Exception - cannot find assembly system.web.http

Tags: postsharp

our project currently needs System.web.http version 5.2.3 but we are using PostSharp version 4.2.28 and getting the following error

> 4>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: Unhandled exception (4.2.28.0,
>   postsharp-net40-x86-srv.exe, CLR 4.0.30319.394806, Release):
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyLoadException: Cannot find assembly
>   'system.web.http, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral,
>   publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35'. [Version mismatch]

Answer (score 1):

I added the following to my csproj file and it solved the problem by redirecting the assemblies to my app.config.

Added:

```
<PropertyGroup> 
    <PostSharpHostConfigurationFile>app.config</PostSharpHostConfigurationFile> 
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem should be solved in PostSharp 5.1.